# Error: Reference to non-static member function must be called for leetcode solution

Tags: c++

I'm trying to sort a vector in C++ of type pair based on the first element. I used to getthe error Error: Reference to non-static member function must be called , but I added static to the sortByFirst function. In my own IDE the solution gets sorted properly but in leetcode the sorting doesn't happen. What is the reason?

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    static bool sortByFirst(const pair<int,vector<int>> &a, const pair<int,vector<int>> &b) {
        return (a.first < b.first);
    }

    vector<vector<int>> kClosest(vector<vector<int>>& points, int k) {

        vector<pair<double, vector<int>>> storingData;
        vector<vector<int>> solution;

        double distance;
        for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            distance = 0;
            distance = sqrt(pow(points[i][0], 2) + pow(points[i][1], 2));
            storingData.push_back(pair<int, vector<int>>(distance, {points[i][0], points[i][1]}));
        }

        sort(storingData.begin(), storingData.end(), &sortByFirst);

        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            solution.push_back(storingData[i].second);
        }

        return solution; 
    }
};
```

Comment: It isn't clear what error you are getting now. Errors that you used to get are irrelevant.

Comment: Generally it's rather pointless to call a non-static member function on an object of a class that has no state. Did you leave out state data from your member function and class to shorten the example code?

Comment: static fixed the error in the title.  So, is it just that leetcode doesn't produce any result at all?